# Closeable items in cart with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, javascript-framework

I want to make a component (pretty much like a shopping cart) that collects user items and those items can be closed (deleted from the shopping cart).

For example, let say a user is asked to give his favorite countries. He's got an inputText backed with autocomplete that helps him write and find a country name. When he hits enter, the item (country name) goes into the component (cart). And whenever his hangs the mouse over the item in the component, an [X] (close sign) appears next to the item that permits the removal of the item from the component.
There are a lot of free Javascript framework (Dojo, jQuery, Kendo UI, etc..) that handle the autocomplete part but apparently none of them handles the "closeable item in cart" functionality.

Do you know any good free JS framework that offers this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too specific to be available out of the box, I am afraid you will have to code the functionality yourself. Using a javascript library like jquery would make this very easy though. But its not just JS, you will need html, css and js play together...